# How to detect response.redirect? (Comparing to postback)

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a question. Often, we use if else for postback in asp.net - for example:

```
if (!IsPostback) {}
else {}
```

Comparing postback to response.redirect, is there any keyword i can use to represent response.redirect in the same fashion inside my page load?

Answer (score 0):

If you do a Response.Redirect, by definition the next page load will not be a postback. If you want to detect, on page load, whether or not the user was Response.Redirect'ed to that page, use a querystring parameter.

Redirecting page:

```
if (shouldRedirect)
{
    Response.Redirect("http://mysite.cool.site/stuff/awesome/webapp/display.aspx?IsRedirect=1");
}
```

Receiving page:

```
if (Request.QueryString["IsRedirect"]=="1")
{
    Do whatever you need to do to account for the fact that you were redirected here.
}
```

Comment: It says "shouldRedirect is not found in the current context"